# Implementing the ISupportIncrementalLoading interface - Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, loading, windows-10, screen-resolution, windows-10-mobile

I try to implement the ISupportIncrementalLoading interface, for when scrollbar comes to the end, load more items in other URL.

Example (Expected scenary): My First Request give me a list of items and one NextURL. 
The next URL need to load more item until the page are full. When I push down scrollbar, loadmore items.

The Problem: This work perfect only in screens with low resolution, when I test this im my second screen with 1680x1050 not load more item after first request (this request give me a NextUrl).

I try to implemet this: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-the-isupportincrementalloading-interface-in-a-window-store-app/

Part of my code different page mentioned before:

```
    private string NextUrl { get; set; }
    private int currentPage;
    private object MyData{ get; set; }

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get {
           return hasMoreItems; 
        }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count = 0)
    {

        var dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(
            async () =>
            {

                var result = await this.Source.GetPage(this.MyData, this.NextUrl , this.CurrentPage++);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.NextUrl ))
                    hasMoreItems = false;
                else
                    hasMoreItems = true;

                if (result != null || result.Items.Count() == 0 )
                {
                    this.NextUrl = result.NextUrl ;
                    resultCount = (uint)result.Items.Count();

                    await dispatcher.RunAsync(
                        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () =>
                        {
                            foreach (ItemType item in result.Items)
                                this.Add(item);
                        });

                    return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = resultCount };
                }
            }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
```

Someone Help me please?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, it asks for more items before you get the NextUrl? You should post the complete code please (where you add items, where you get that url)

Comment: @FilippoB, I edit my post, thanks for your help. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the number of items from the first request don't fill the whole screen, so `LoadModeItemsAsync()` is called twice (or more) very fast, before the first request finishes.

To handle this, I would add a `boolean` marker that you set to true when you start fetching data and the false when you finish the task. At the beginning of the loading function you just check that this value is set to false before start downloading more data.

```
private string NextUrl { get; set; }
private int currentPage;
private object MyData { get; set; }

private bool _isLoading = false;

public bool isLoading
{
    get { return _isLoading; }
    set { _isLoading = value; }
}

public bool HasMoreItems
{
    get
    {
        return hasMoreItems;
    }
}

private async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadDataAsync()
{

    if (!isLoading)
        isLoading = true;
    else
        return new LoadMoreItemsResult { Count = (uint)this.Count };

    var result = await this.Source.GetPage(this.MyData, this.NextUrl, this.CurrentPage++);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.NextUrl))
        hasMoreItems = false;
    else
        hasMoreItems = true;

    if (result != null || result.Items.Count() == 0)
    {
        this.NextUrl = result.NextUrl;
        resultCount = (uint)result.Items.Count();

        await dispatcher.RunAsync(
            CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                foreach (ItemType item in result.Items)
                    this.Add(item);
            });
    }
    isLoading = false;

    return new LoadMoreItemsResult { Count = (uint)this.resultCount }; ;
}

public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count = 0)
{
    return LoadDataAsync().AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 
I change in my projecto the code and the problem are the same.
After first request don't call NextUrl, nothing more really happen!
:(

Comment: @fipcurren88 debug the app an see how variables get updated. I can't see any other problem here

Comment: I do it, but don't understand the problem, I set breakpoint in all lines but not understant, after that problem, the code not fired in property HasMoreItems.